chrome extensions manifest v3 clone to edge extensions
my microsoft edge appearance is Light theme
But my extensions manifest version v3 sidepanel is Dark. For example:


Manfest V3 Settings Code:


{
  "short_name": "sample",
  "name": "sample-edge-theme-ui",
  "description": "edge theme ui",
  "manifest_version": 3,
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "background": {
    "service_worker": "background.js"
  },
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": [
        "<all_urls>"
      ],
      "js": [
        "content.js"
      ]
    }
  ],
  "permissions": [
    "storage",
    "activeTab",
    "sidePanel",
    "contextMenus",
    "scripting",
    "tabs"
  ],
  "host_permissions": [
    "<all_urls>"
  ],
  "web_accessible_resources": [
    {
      "resources": [
        "prompts.json"
      ],
      "matches": [
        "<all_urls>"
      ]
    }
  ],
  "action": {
    "default_icon": {
      "16": "icon-16.png",
      "32": "icon-32.png",
      "48": "icon-48.png",
      "128": "icon-128.png"
    },
  },
  "icons": {
    "16": "icon-16.png",
    "32": "icon-32.png",
    "48": "icon-48.png",
    "128": "icon-128.png"
  }
}



I don't know how to solve it?
Micosoft Edge Version
Macos:
Microsoft Edge
Version 129.0.2792.65 (正式版本) (arm64)
CSS cannot solve this question
html, body {
background: #fff
}

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Ok, I will provide enough code! Thanks

Now you can check the manifest V3 settings code is right
